# Deploying to heroku failed because sqlite3 is in the gems, even though it's not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku, deployment, sqlite

So I switched to postgresql from sqlite3 which is what I built the app with. I would love to deploy to heroku and I know that sqlite isn't compatible so I deleted it from my app in the db directory, removed the gem, etc. However when I try to do my first push to heroku master it says sqlite3 is in my gemfile which causes the push to fail. WTF! ha. I removed it from my gemfile and I don't see it in the gemfile lock. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you update your `Gemfile.lock` too?

Comment: Yeah. I think I found a solution though. I'll post an answer

Comment: Nevermind. Now the issue is with sqlite3. Edited the question

Comment: "I don't see it in the gemfile lock"—please be _very sure_ about this. There's a difference between "I don't see it" and "it's not there". Use something like `grep` or the find tool in your favourite text editor to make sure it's not there.

Comment: Have you checked that you’re using the correct adapter in database.yml? It should be `adapter: postgresql`. Otherwise Rails thows an error about the gem not being present which is easy to confuse for a gemfile/bundler issue.

Comment: I actually successfully deplpoyed. But now there's an internal server 500 error. Ugh. The fun never ends

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If you need to config the Gemfile look like this;

```
group :production do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end
```

And `bundle install` to update your Gemfile again.